# Where does Goose even come from, was he Danvers’ pet before the incident?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

Goose the cat from *Captain Marvel* is odd to me...

He's really a Flerken, a weird alien that looks like a cat, so why would Danvers have an alien pet?  Maybe Marr-Vell gave it to her?  Seems unlikely given the trepidation inhibited by Talos when first presented with Goose.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, Goose was the pet of Mar-Vell.

After the death of her owner, Goose went along with Carol and Nick Fury into their mission to find Mar-Vell's laboratory.

You might remember the scene in the movie where they run into Goose in the hallways and Nick starts petting her. And then when they escape the base, Goose is there with them in the plane.

After that, Goose stayed with Fury at S.H.I.E.L.D.

Sources:
<sub>[Goose](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Goose),
[Captain Marvel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Marvel_(film))</sub>

Comment: But didn't they first meet Goose at the SHIELD base in the hallway?  Why do we think it was Mar-Vell's pet?  Why was it still there?  Would an orphaned cat really be kept around as the office pet of such a locked down institution?  I feel like I missed something with how Goose got there, but given he's such a critical character I think it should have been better explained.

Comment: @user1717828 It was the project Pegasus base, where Mar-Vell used to work. Since Mar-Vell works a lot, she brought Goose with her to work, and when she died, Goose stayed there...

Comment: Can confirm. Source: Am Goose

Comment: @user1717828 We see Goose in Carol's memory flashbacks from her old life on Earth, on the base with Mar-Vell.